# WordPress json api plugin - calling from jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, getjson

I am using [JSON API Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/) for wordpress. It generates a json file from my wordpress content at http://grmmph.com/?json=1.

It seems to work fine if from the link above, however when I am trying to call it with jQuery, it doesn't get any call.

```
        var url = "http://grmmph.com/?json=1&count=1"; 
        jQuery.getJSON(url, function() {
        alert('Test!'); // Test if it is even working, not alert appears.
    });
```

Any ideas? maybe a better json plugin for wordpress?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74773/javascript-included-but-alert-function-not-working/74776#74776

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of that. Anyway it still doesn't solves my problem. When I am typing an other JSON address into 'url' the alert pop ups, meaning the problem is the the url string or and the json file.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I struggled in the past to find the good way to use JSON with Wordpress and be able to fetch the result using jQuery. I hope the answer I wrote (and accepted) will be helpful for you.

[result of get_the_content() not correctly displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753853/result-of-get-the-content-not-correctly-displayed)

Comment: what is new about this issue?